# How to create new array element and add at end of array using jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an Array of objects and need to add new object as per some criteria. As consist list of objects as:

[image]

How to create new object which have all above properties and add to end of array using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `push()` method of the array to do this:

```
// assuming 'arr' is the variable containing the array you showed in the question:
arr.push({
    AgentOnlyFieldFlag: 'False',
    // other properties here...
});
```

[**More info on push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Also note that you should really change the `AgentOnlyFieldFlag`, `BlankCaptionFlag` and `PromatchFlag` to contain boolean values instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

1.you can create a plain object in jquery

Ex:

var foo = { foo: "bar", hello: "world" };

refer : http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

2.you can create array in jquery

Ex:

var array = new Array();

3. push elements into an array

Ex: array.push(foo);

refer : https://www.sitepoint.com/declare-arrays-jquery/